# Why is correct value for count returned first time though for loop?

Tags: python, parsing, loops

In the for loop below, I am trying to understand why the correct value for `count` is only returned the first time the loop runs.

I'm creating a parsing program to look for certain strings in a a text file and count them.  However, I'm having some trouble with one spot.

```
def callbrowse():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text files", "*.txt"),("HTML files", ".html;*.htm"),("All files", "*.*")))
    print filename
    try:
        global filex
        global writefile
        filex = open(filename, 'r')
        print "Success!!"
        print filename
    except:
        print "Failed to open file"

######This returns the correct count only the first time it is run.  The next time it  ######returns 0.  If the browse button is clicked again, then this function returns the ######correct count again.
def count_errors(error_name):
    count = 0
    for line in filex:
        if error_name == "CPU > 79%":
            stringparse = "Utilization is above"
        elif error_name == "Stuck touchscreen":
            stringparse = "Stuck touchscreen"
        if re.match("(.*)" + "Utilization is above" + "(.*)",line):
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Thanks for any help.  I can't seem to get this to work right.

Comment: Hm...  Your code is very hard to read.  Please try adding some linebreaks and indentation to make it more legible.

Comment: I don't see a point in the code where you actually call count_errors...

Answer (score 5):

The method works only the first time because the file is passed through the end.
If you call the method again there are no more lines.
You have the reset the file position by calling filex.seek(0) before the for loop.